# Sequelize upsert is always creating/inserting a new entry on post request, instead of updating data on matching username. MySQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a survey for a specific amount of users.
When a user first submits their answers I want to create a new entry in the database, this part works fine. If the same user wants to retake the survey I want to update their answers instead of creating a new entry for the same user.

I'm trying to use sequelize upsert but it keeps creating new entries for the same "testuser" every time I make a new post request.

None of the answers found online seemed to work. Any help on what I might be doing wrong is appreciated.

```
// parts of the code that might not be relevant to the problem have been omitted
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: 'database',
  username: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  dialect: 'mysql',
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => console.log('Connection has been established successfully.'))
  .catch(err => console.log('error: ', err));

const SurveyResults = sequelize.define('results', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  results: {
    type: Sequelize.JSON,
  },
});

SurveyResults.sync()
  .then(() => console.log('Survey results table created'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


app.post('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  let { username, surveyData } = req.body;

  SurveyResults.upsert(
    {
      name: username,
      results: surveyData,
    },
    { name: username }
  )
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5050;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server is running on port ' + PORT));
```

Comment: I don't know this language, but I doubt that a pk *also* needs to be defined as unique.

Comment: Setting it to unique might have been redundant, I made the change. Ty for your answer but the problem still persists.

Comment: If you try to insert a row with the same `name` using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` the issue is not shown?

Comment: @Anatoly using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with the same name created new entries.

Comment: Ok, check PK and an unique index definitions in a DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pk doesnt have to be unique, it's redundant.

If username is not primary key, create another unique index on that column and upsert will work as create if same username is not found, update if same username already exists in table.

Comment: Isn't `sequelize.define` setting `name` as pk?

Comment: Check if `name` has uniqueness set in database manually first, if not make it `unique` by adding unique index on it.

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue even though the console.log is showing ` _previousDataValues: { name: undefined, results: undefined, id: null },` on the second entry. I might be misunderstanding the console.log and expecting to see the previous values there, I hope that's not important. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Upsert on mysql work only if the same primary key is given in not this will create a new one .

you can refer to : [https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-upsert)